# React - Network Error when sending POST request only when on HTTPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, heroku, https

I have a web application where the front-end is done with React (create-react-app) and it is deployed on Heroku. The back-end is done with node.js/express and it runs on an Amazon EC2. 
I don't have any problem getting the app to work when I deploy the front-end on localhost or on Heroku if I access it with HTTP as http://myapp.heroku.com. The problem arises when I access it with HTTPS (which is the default on Heroku) as https://myapp.heroku.com. When I do so and send a request to the node.js server on the Amazon EC2, I get the following error:

```
Error: Network Error
Stack trace:
createError@https://myapp.herokuapp.com/static/js/bundle.js:1555:15
handleError@https://myapp.herokuapp.com/static/js/bundle.js:1091:14
```

Here is the part in the front-end which send the request to the node.js server:

```
_deflateAscii(valueAscii){
axios.post('//My-EC2-Instance-Here.compute.amazonaws.com:80/deflate/ascii', {inflatedAscii: valueAscii}).then(res => {
  this.setState(
    {
      inflatedAscii: valueAscii,
      inflatedHex: res.data.inflatedHex,
      deflatedBase64: res.data.deflatedBase64,
      deflatedHex: res.data.deflatedHex
    },
    this._setTextBoxesValues
  );
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err)});
  }
```

Here are the modules I use on the server-side:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
```

And the part handling coming request from the front-end:

```
app.post('/deflate/ascii', function(req, res){
try{
  console.log('request received');
  var inflatedHexValue = convert.asciiToHex(req.body.inflatedAscii);
  var deflatedBase64Value = deflate.asciiToBase64(req.body.inflatedAscii);
  var deflatedHexValue = deflate.asciiToHex(req.body.inflatedAscii);
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
  res.status(500).send(err);
}
response = {
  deflatedBase64: deflatedBase64Value,
  deflatedHex: deflatedHexValue,
  inflatedHex: inflatedHexValue
};
res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
console.log('response sent');
});
```

When I get the Network Error on the front-end, the node.js server does not receive the request, but I have done some diagnostics with Wireshark and there is and handshake with the EC2 server, but the traffic ends there without any HTTP traffic:

[TCP-traffic between https://myapp.heroku.com/ and My-EC2-Instance-Here.compute.amazonaws.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHHlv.jpg)

Do I need SSL on the backend if the frontend is HTTPS? From this post I understood that it can also do without [Do we need ssl certificate for both front end and backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407389/do-we-need-ssl-certificate-for-both-front-end-and-backend#42407583). This is just a course project anyway and there is only meaningless strings going back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit your site over https in a browser, you need to disable blocking of mixed content (http and https). As a result your browser classifies the connection as not secure.
So yes it would be good to use SSL/TSL both for backend and frontend.

Alos did you try to use

```js
res.json(response);
res.status(200).end();
```

or set the headers to application/json?
I recommend to put your res calls into the try catch block, because your `res.end` will be executed anyway.