# Do we need to give ssl certificate files with angular build files for the live / production deployment?

Tags: angular, apache, ssl, iis, https

Earlier our production environment was running on `http://` protocol, but now we bought `ssl` certificate to make our domain run on secure protocol `https://`. Deployment team kept the certificate in backend server `Apache` somehow. But when hitting the domain name, it is saying

> Application can't be reachable with `https://` protocol

As usual I gave the build files for the deployment, do we need to do anything special while doing `ng build` to add ssl folder something like that.

I've gone through articles given below

[Running Angular CLI over HTTPS with a Trusted Certificate](https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a)

[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201058/run-angular-2-app-over-http-and-https-both)

[Another Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407389/do-we-need-ssl-certificate-for-both-front-end-and-backend)

But I didn't get the point that, what we need to do to run angular app successfully on `https://` protocol

Thank you for your Information / Suggestion

Comment: HTTPS connection is created early in the browser/server communication, so check with your deployment team and network administrators to install the certificate on the first device. Then other setup can follow.